# How to get a value from SQLite to convert it?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, bitcoin

So I have an issue, I am trying to convert a float value from SQLite Db.
The value represents a price in USD and I want to convert it in BTC, I was installing python-forex but because I do not have experience enough I am stack on this:

```
b = BtcConverter(force_decimal=True)
p = float(acf1.p1)
pbtc = b.convert_to_btc(10, 'USD')
```

What I need to do is to exchange "10" with "p", and "p" is a row from my SQlite Db.

I was trying to get acfi.p1 from db table with:

```
acf1 = KAch.query.order_by(KAch.reg.desc()).all()
```

As well the html code is:

```
{{ "%.9f" %pbtc }}
```

But because I am new is giving me 500 error.

Could you give me a hint?

Update:

```
@app.route('/adfa', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_foa():
    t1=request.form.get('t1')
    c1=request.form.get('c1')
    p1=request.form.get('p1')
    p2=request.form.get('p2')
    um1=request.form.get('um1')
    ce1=request.form.get('ce1')
    dc1=request.form.get('dc1')
    mdla1=request.form.get('mdla1')
    mdam1=request.form.get('mdam1')
    aop=request.form.get('aop')
    pz1=request.form.get('pz1')
    users_id = request.form.get('users_id')

    acf1 = KAch(
                t1=t1,
                c1=c1,
                p1=p1,
                p2=p2,
                um1=um1,
                ce1=ce1,
                dc1=dc1,
                mdla1=mdla1,
                mdam1=mdam1,
                aop=aop,
                pz1=pz1,
                users_id=current_user.id,
                reg=datetime.now())

    db.session.add(acf1)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('adfa', users_id=current_user.id, _external=True))

@app.route('/profil/<int:users_id>')
@login_required
def profil(users_id):
    ac1 = KAch.query.order_by(KAch.reg.desc()).all()
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=users_id).first()
    profil1 = KProfil.query.filter_by(id=users_id).one()

    b = BtcConverter(force_decimal=True)
    #p = float(acf1.p1)
    pbtc = b.convert_to_btc(10, 'USD')

    if 'out' in current_user.tc:
        return redirect(url_for('adpro', users_id=current_user.id, _external=True))
    elif 'n' in current_user.tc:
        return redirect(url_for('logout', _external=True))

    return render_template('front/usr/usr.html', profil1=profil1, user=user, ac1=ac1, pbtc=pbtc)
```

Comment: Are you trying to query the sqlite table by the help of a custom library? Can you share the docs which led you to try `acf1 = KAch.query.order_by(KAch.reg.desc()).all()`?

Comment: it is helping you what I have added as update on my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution I found it is easy and is working!

Server side:

```
b = BtcConverter(force_decimal=True)
p1btc = b.get_latest_price('USD')
p1btcr = b.get_latest_price('RON')
pbtc = b.convert_to_btc(10, 'USD')
pron = float(Decimal(p1btcr))
```

HTML side:

```
{{ acf1.p1 / pron }}
```